# How to access AWS RDS instance from local PC

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to access AWS RDS instance from my local PC.

I followed trouble-shooting procedure from :

[How can I troubleshoot connectivity to an Amazon RDS instance that uses a public or private subnet of a VPC?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connectivity-instance-subnet-vpc/)

I checked **Public accessibility** is **YES**

and switched to public subnet, but still cannot access RDS instance.

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RDS has a security group attached, You need to white list your public ip in the security group, so that you can access the database from your pc.

#### Find the security group

- Goto amazon RDS console
- Click `Databases on the left
- Click to select your database instance from the list of databases
- Under the `connectivity and Security` tab, you can find the option called `VPC security groups`
- Click the Security group name to add your public ip address

#### Adding your public ip to the security group

- Select the `inbound rules` tab
- Click the `Edit`
- Select the type of database in the `type` column, for e.g mysql
- Under the `Source` column , select `My IP`
- Also give a meaningful description, such as `my home`

Note: Many internet service providers allocates dynamic ip addresses instead of static ip address, which means your ip address may change frequently. Hence you need to add your new ip address to the security group when this happens.

Comment: Modified again, have a look

Comment: Just followed your procedure, worked great ! Even though my IP is a dynamic one, it has not changed for a couple of years now.
Thanks again.

Comment: pleasure helping you, But consider moving your RDS to private subnet as @Jonathan suggested if you are planning to keep this instance for a while, because it's not very safe to have the RDS running in the public subnet.

Comment: Agreed, this is just a testbed, which will be removed in a few days.

Answer (score 7):

My strategy for local development has usually been:

Have RDS instance in a private VPC.

Have an EC2 instance (cheapest one you can find) on the private VPC but also public SSH access.

Create an SSH tunnel through the EC2 instance to the RDS instance.

Configure your dev environment to connect to the SSH tunnel.

This is usually much easier to configure (and more secure to boot)